Question on Probability notation, Billingsley Probability and Measure
I'm reading section 8 in Billingsley's Probability and Measure on Markov Chains. He's using some notation I'm not fully understanding. In 8.12 in the photo below, can someone explain why the second term on the right hand side of the equality is
\begin{align*}
P_{i_m}[X_1 = j_1, ..., X_n = j_n]
\end{align*}
rather than
\begin{align*}
P_{i_m}[X_{m+1} = j_1, ..., X_{m+n} = j_n]
\end{align*}
Some context: $P[X_1 = i_1 \mid X_0 = i_0]=p_{i_0i_0}$ and so on.
Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify. Thanks!


$\alpha_i$ denotes $P[X_0 = i]$

Billingsley is probably assuming the chain is homogeneous, that is,
$$P[X_{m+1}=j_1, \dots, X_{m+n}=j_n | X_m=j]=P[X_{1}=j_1, \dots, X_{n}=j_n | X_0=j].$$
Some authors include this condition in the definition of Markov chains, but i cannot verify if Billingsley does so.
If homogeneity is assumed, we have
$$P_i[X_1=i_1, \dots, X_m=i_m, X_{m+1}=j_1, \dots, X_{m+n}=j_m]\\
=P_i[X_1=i_1, \dots, X_m=i_m] P_i[X_{m+1}=j_1\dots X_{m+n}=j_m | X_1=i_1, \dots, X_m=i_m] 
\\ = P_i[X_1=i_1, \dots, X_m=i_m] P_i[X_{m+1}=j_1\dots X_{m+n}=j_m  | X_m=i_m] =P_i[X_1=i_1, \dots, X_m=i_m] P_{i_m}[X_{1}=j_1\dots X_{n}=j_m]$$

In the last equality, the right term should be $P_{i_m}$ right?

Billingsley says the transition probabilities are stationary. Is that the same thing as homogeneity (or implies it)? I guess another way of putting what I'm wondering: what assumptions are usually made to make the chain homogenous? Thank you.

After some reflection, I think this answers the crux of my question. Thank you!

Yes, there is a typo, and stationarity of the transition probabilities is the same as time homogeneity, I believe.
